# Colors 'locking on' to similar colors in Flutter/Dart AVD

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, android-virtual-device

I am new to Flutter and Dart programming but I am having an issue with the colors that I can't seem to find anything about online.

I am trying to get a very specific shade of purple (R: 16, G: 15, B: 25, O: 1). The issue is that when I put this color into Flutter using Color.fromRGBO(16, 15, 25, 1) I get a shade of magenta or something similar (very pinkish).

I tried lowering the R value by just 1 from 16 to 15 and now it goes an indigo or a saturated dark blue color.

I thought that I was going crazy or something so I tried inputting the RGBO values into a color picker and they look normal on there.

Next I tried using the Hex codes instead of RGBO and it still looked odd. I watched a video on how to use colors in Flutter and they were able to easily get exact colors whereas mine seem to lock on to a close color and stick to it.

When I tried to use my actual phone instead of the AVD it looked just fine however.

Is there some sort of setting that limits the range of colors that my emulator can display?

It would be inconvenient if I had to use my actual phone every time I wanted to test out a color scheme as my cable is very finicky and disconnects often.

[image: RGBO: 16, 15, 25, 1]
RGBO: 16, 15, 15, 1

[image: RGBO: 15, 15, 25, 1]
RGBO: 16, 15, 15, 1